# How to write sub2ind in C code, from Matlab code

Tags: c, matlab, matrix, indexing

Assume that you have this matrix

```
>> P = zeros(8, 12)
P =

   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

And you want to add `1` on each coordinate. If it's the same coordinate, it will be still `1`.

```
>> angles = [1 2 1 3 3 2 5 6 2 1 3 8]
angles =

   1   2   1   3   3   2   5   6   2   1   3   8

>> r = [1 2 4 2 5 6 1 4 6 6 3 6]
r =

   1   2   4   2   5   6   1   4   6   6   3   6
```

If I use `sub2ind`

```
>> indices = sub2ind(size(P), angles, r);
>> P(indices) = P(indices) + 1;
>> P
P =

   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Ass you can see, `angles` and `r` have two identical coordinate `(2, 6)`, but the `P` matrix only got `1`.

If I would do this in `C` code, then it would look something like this

```
for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
   for(int j = 0; j < column; j++){
     P[angles[i]* column + r[j]] += 1.0f;
   }
}
```

But the problem is that that for-loop is not even close to `sub2ind` method.
I understand how `sub2ind` works, because Matlab is in `Column Major` and `C` is in `Row major`.

**Question:**

How can `sub2ind` we written in `C` code and give the same result as it was Matlab-code?

Comment: To avoid incrementing an element twice, you need to remove duplicates from your indices. I would first compute the array of linear indices from `angles` and `r`, then sort that array, then it’s easy to spot duplicates (because they’d be consecutive).

Comment: To have the _ceiling_ value of `1`, don't use `+=`... Simply assign `1` to the cell, perhaps replacing `1` with `1`... The whole "row vs. col major" issue seems to be not well understood. An example without duplicated values in `angles` or `r` would be helpful... (PS: Write a clean function, then, if necessary, write `transpose()` to swap the major/minor aspect....)

Comment: In C, it would be better to simply use a two-dimensional array, rather than using a one-dimensional array and manually doing the index calculations.  C supports dynamically sized arrays.

Comment: As for column major vs. row major, just swap the indices.

Comment: @CrisLuengo It's much cleaner, and would probably produce the same code.  I never said it would be faster.  It's just much better style.  So, yes, it would be "better", exactly as I said.  Let the compiler create the flattened index for you.  It's clearer and less error-prone.  You couldn't do it in old K&R C, but in modern C you can.

Comment: @CrisLuengo You can easily allocate arrays of arrays on the heap. People do it all the time. `int (*p)[width] = malloc(height * sizeof(int [width]));`.  That should do it.  K&R required fixed array dimensions, but with modern C they can be variable, as shown.  Note that `sizeof(int [width])` is just `sizeof(*p)`.

Comment: @TomKarzes That’s interesting! Thanks! I guess you can tell I haven’t written C in a long while. I’m reading up on how to pass this into and out of functions.

Comment: @CrisLuengo The relevant change since K&R C is that modern C now supports variable array dimensions.  You can do things like declare `int arr[n];` within a function, and the allocated size will be determined by `n`.  That replaces the old `alloca` call.  But it can also be used to pointers to arrays, as in this case.  And `sizeof` will correctly determine the size based on the current value of the array dimension.

Comment: @CrisLuengo To pass types like this to functions, you just need to pass the dimension variable before the array variable.  So you can do `int foo(int w, int (*p)[w])` for example.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Now that I think about it, instead of `height * sizeof(int [width])`, you should be able to do `sizeof(int [height][width])`. That seems cleaner to me. They're both equivalent to `height * width * sizeof(int)`. 
 You should even be able to do it with 1-d arrays. So instead of `len * sizeof(char)`, you should be able to do `sizeof(char [len])`.